# Why is my SSH tunnel from Windows not working and why am I getting verbose output related to Kubernetes?

Tags: windows, docker, ssh-tunnel

I set up an ssh tunnel from my windows 10 machine to a linux box over port 5001.  I set up a netcat listener on the linux box and verified it is listening correctly by sending a message to it from the local linux box.  I've set up an ssh tunnel using Putty (which I've done a million times) from my Windows box to the linux box over port 5001.  When I run netcat on my windows machine to send a message in verbose mode:

```
nc -vvv 127.0.0.1 5001 < message.txt
```

The connection just times out and I get the message:

```
kubernetes.docker.internal [127.0.0.1] 5001 (?) open
```

The only thing I can think of that this would be related to is that I recently installed "Docker Desktop For Windows".  I don't know why netcat would be going through Docker, but it seems like it may be a Docker related issue.  Any ideas on how to resolve this problem would be appreciated.

If I disable all of the entries related to kubernetes/docker in the hosts file and re-run the command I get:

```
myhost.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1] 5001 (?) open
```

I can see that port 5001 is being listened to on my windows machine because when I do a "netstat -an" I can see it:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5001         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5001         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:5001             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:5001             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact answer to your question, but I sure it will guide you to fix your ssh tunnel issue.
you can stop the ssh tunnel and try netstat to find out what service using the port 5001
for the example I have list / grep all the connections for localhost:

```
  C:\Users\myuser>netstat -ano | findstr "Proto" && netstat -ano | findstr "127.0.0.1"
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54235        127.0.0.1:62522        ESTABLISHED     11280
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54451        127.0.0.1:54452        ESTABLISHED     12300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54452        127.0.0.1:54451        ESTABLISHED     12300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55337        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6976
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57147        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13432
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4084
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        127.0.0.1:54235        ESTABLISHED     4084
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    12672
  UDP    127.0.0.1:50292        *:*                                    832
  UDP    127.0.0.1:54549        *:*                                    10680
  UDP    127.0.0.1:56491        *:*                                    12316
  UDP    127.0.0.1:57739        *:*                                    20800
  UDP    127.0.0.1:58253        *:*                                    6976
  UDP    127.0.0.1:58950        *:*                                    3116
  UDP    127.0.0.1:60327        *:*                                    2128
  UDP    127.0.0.1:64274        *:*                                    12672

C:\Users\myuser>

-a            Displays all connections and listening ports.
-n            Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
-o            Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.
```

Then using PID you can find which causing the issue for the example I used follwing connection

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:55337        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6976

C:\Users\myuser>tasklist | findstr 6976
com.docker.proxy.exe          6976 Console                    1      9,696 K

C:\Users\myuser>
```

Comment: Good thought.  However when I do that, nothing else is allocated to the port.  It seems more like some sort of routing problem.

Comment: is there any host entry ? similar to
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal 

if so comment that entry and try ssh tunnel again

Comment: Sha, yeah there was an entry in the hosts file for that.  I commented it out and now I get "no destination: NO_DATA (11004:11004)".  I assume traffic is trying to sen to the "kubernetes.docker.internal" host and since I commented it out, it doesn't know how to resolve that name.

Comment: If I remove all the hosts entries related to docker, I get the message "myhost.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1] 5001 (?) open"